# Natural Join Query returns zero results even if the column name is same and have single matching column

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL workbench 6.0.

I have following tables:

Actor, film_Actors

both have only one common column with name actor_id and have the same data type.

Sample Data:

select * from actor; gives:

[image]

and select * from film_actor; gives:

[image]

But when I ran Natural join query:

select actor_id, first_name, film_id from actor natural join film_actor;

Zero rows are returned. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `natural join` will join using all columns that exist in both tables.

In your case, that includes `last_update`, and that is probably not what you want.

It is usually a good idea not to use `natural join` for reasons like this.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like a query showing a film name with the actors name in the same row. I'd use a inner join in this case:

```
SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, f.film_id FROM actor a INNER JOIN film_actor f on a.actor_ID=f.actor_id
```